# javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: Cannot use a Temporary destination from another Connection

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I have a producer which connects to ActiveMQ broker to send me messages to the client.

1. Since it expects some response from the client, it first creates a temp queue and associates it to the **JMS replyto** header.
2. It then sends the message over to the broker and waits for the response on temp queue from the client.
3. Receives the response from the client over the temp queue, performs required actions and then exits.

This works fine most of the times, but sporadically the application throws error messsages saying " Cannot use queue created from another connection ".

I am unable to identify what could cause this to happen as the temp queue is being created from the current session itself.

Did anyone else come across this situation and knows how to fix it?

Code snippet:

```
Connection conn = myJmsTemp. getConnectionFactory().createConnection();
ses = conn.createSession(transacted,ackMode);
responseQueue = ses.createTemporaryQueue();
...
MyMessageCreator msgCrtr = new MyMessageCreator(objects,responseQueue);
myJmsTemp.send(dest, msgCrtr);
myJmsTemp.setReceiveTimeout(timeout);
ObjectMessage response = (ObjectMessage)myJmsTemplate.receive(responseQueue);
```

Here `MyMessageCreator` implements `MessageCreator` interface.

All am trying to do is send a message to the broker and wait for a response from the client over the temp queue. Also am using a pooled connection factory to get the connection.

Answer (score 3):

You get an error like this if you have a client that is trying to subscribe as a consumer on a temporary destination that was created by a different connection instance.  The JMS spec defines that only the connection that created the temp destination can consume from it, so that's why the limitation exists.  As for the reason you are seeing it its hard to say without seeing your code that encounters the error.

Given that your update says you are using the Pooled connection factory I'd guess that this is the root of you issue.  If the consume call happens to use a different connection from the Pool than the one that created the temp destination then you would see the error that you mentioned.

Comment: This is the code snippet:<br/>

Connection conn = myJmsTemp. getConnectionFactory().createConnection();<br/>
ses = conn.createSession(transacted,ackMode);<br/>
responseQueue = ses.createTemporaryQueue();<br/>
...<br/>
MyMessageCreator msgCrtr = new MyMessageCreator(objects,responseQueue);<br/>
myJmsTemp.send(dest, msgCrtr);<br/>
myJmsTemp.setReceiveTimeout(timeout);<br/>
ObjectMessage response = (ObjectMessage)myJmsTemplate.receive(responseQueue);<br/>
MyMessageCreator class implements MessageCreator and implements the createmessage method.
Can you make out anything odd in this?

Comment: I can really read this unformatted code, can you edit your original post and add some code sections to show what it is you are doing?

Comment: Tim, I have added the formatted code snippet to the original post. Am not trying to get a new connection or reinitialize the connection object anywhere. Please note that the producer works fine most of the times but few times it has thrown the error that we are discussing here.

Comment: Updated my answer to indicate what is most likely the cause

Comment: I was under an assumption that during the whole process of send message to broker -> wait for response on temp queue -> get response on the temp queue, the same connection would be used. Please correct me if am wrong. So, in this case is there any work around to do away with this error msg?

Comment: Each call into the JMSTemplate can use a different connection in the pool, so your call to receive could be using a different connection then the one you created earlier.

Comment: Oh got it now. Thanks for explaining Tim.